# asp.net MVC / SQL Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am a beginner in asp.net MVC. Importing table data using JSON, on column is float when I use `databasename.columnname.ToString()`  I end up with this number `9.026169838000000e+009` however it should read `9026169838`.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: You want to name database table column as "902616938"? if so then why?

Comment: The table column name is Membership and database name is members; so my script is members.Membership.ToString().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are processing the returning json in a javascript application, you can try the following code:

```
Number(databasename.columnname).toFixed(0).ToString()
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not work, Iam using C#; the error is System.Nullable<double>' does not contain a definition for 'toFixed' and no extension method 'toFixed' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<double>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user373721, you could try some string format properties of double. For example, you can use databasename.columnname.Value.ToString("N0")... You can find more info on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I got this error Method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL. Here is my complete code:

Comment: select new{i = visit.ClientId,cell = new string[] { visit.Client.Membership.Value.ToString("N0")}
                    }).ToArray()
            };
            return Json(jsonData);
        }

Comment: @user373721, could you show me more code? try to past the complete class on https://gist.github.com and let me know. It shouldn't be a hard issue...

Comment: @user373721, I will ask you to do an ugly thing. Change your code with the following line: double.Parse(visit.Client.Membership.Value.ToString()).ToString("0") and let me know if it works

Comment: :) Glad it worked!!! The point here is that LinqToSql does some special translates between c# and sql. So, we need to use some method that LinqToSql mapper will understand and, after we get the information we want, we can use a more suitable method to solve our problem. I am sure there are more elegant solutions, but I can't find one now.. :)